# Close my JFrame using the opposite of this

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I currently have

```
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long end = start + 60*1000; 
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
            {

            }
```

At the moment it's waiting 60 seconds to open my JFrame, which is what I need. But in a seperate one I need it to do the opposite of this and start a timer when it is opened and then close the JFrame after 60seconds. Is there a way I can use this but in reverse?

Comment: Yes, use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer there's no opposite of this at all?

Comment: What do you mean? You start a `Timer` with a delay of 1 minute, when it triggers, you close window

Comment: What you need is a simple timer in both cases.   It's not *opposite*.

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475255/dispose-a-frame-inside-a-listener-after-3-secs/13481812#13481812) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216109/java-ending-a-jframe/32216164#32216164)

Comment: Ok ok, I'll take a look, thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users you can use `Timer` to do this.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.pack();

//60 * 1000 is the delay in milliseconds (60 seconds)
final Timer closeTimer = new Timer(60 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       frame.setVisible(false);
   }
});

new Timer(60 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       frame.setVisible(true);
       closeTimer.start();
   }
}).start();
```